# What modules to use for a synchronization service in Java/Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm willing to build a synchronization service in Java. The use case is, that i'm fetching data from an exchange-service (via Exchange Web Services), normalize the data a bit (process probably) and then write it to a backend via GraphQL. I already had a look around the spring modules, but am not quite sure what modules to use. I found spring batch and spring quartz.
The synchronization will have to trigger all X seconds, fetch information from the Exchange, look what's in the backend already and update what's needed.

Do you guys have any suggestions? I started implementing this whole thing in nodejs before, but as it has to run on both, Windows Servers and Docker/Linux, it has been a real pain to keep it running smooth (mostly because bundling nodejs to an application for Windows is pain).

Comment: What I understood From use case is You want some process which will fetch data from .  Web Services -> Does normalization - > Write it into the some persistence store . right ?  now you want process after specific time interval right? If i'm wrong

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! Partly right.
From time to time i want to trigger a sync. That fetches data from a web service (i'm using a package for that), processes it, and "writes" it to another web service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Difference between Spring Batch & Quartz:**

1. Spring Batch and Quartz  have different goals. Spring Batch provides functionality for **processing large volumes of data** and Quartz provides functionality for **scheduling tasks.**
2. So Quartz could complement Spring Batch, A common combination would be to use Quartz as a trigger for a Spring Batch job using a **Cron** expression.

**Conclusion :** So basically Spring Batch defines what should be done, Quartz defines when it should be done.

Quartz is a scheduling framework. Like "execute something every hour or every last friday of the month"

Spring Batch is a framework that defines that "something" that will be executed.
 You can define a job, that consists of steps. Usually a step is something that consists of item reader, optional item processor and item writer, but you can define a custom stem. You can also tell Spring batch to commit on every 10 items and a lot of other stuff.

You can use Quartz to start Spring Batch jobs.

**Recommended for your use case :** 
Quartz scheduling as you want trigger after specific interval.

Reference :https://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/faq.html